# pushd error in shell script from ubuntu20.04 installed from Microsoft store

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, window, pushd

Please Note, I have installed ubuntu20.04 from Microsoft store in Windows Machine.

I would like to perform all operations inside container and want zip file in my local system,but pushd is looking for local directory. Kindly suggest.

```
#!/bin/bash
RUNTIME=python3.7


SELENIUM_VER=3.141.0
CHROME_BINARY_VER=v1.0.0-55 # based on Chromium 69.0.3497.81
CHROMEDRIVER_VER=2.43       # supports Chrome v69-71

#mkdir -p out/build/chrome_headless/python/lib/$RUNTIME/site-packages
OUT_DIR=out/build/chrome_headless/python/lib/$RUNTIME/site-packages

docker run -v $(pwd):/out -it lambci/lambda:build-$RUNTIME pip install selenium==$SELENIUM_VER --target $OUT_DIR
    
pushd build/chrome_headless

DRIVER_URL=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VER/chromedriver_linux64.zip
curl -SL $DRIVER_URL >chromedriver.zip
unzip chromedriver.zip
rm chromedriver.zip

# download chrome binary
CHROME_URL=https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/$CHROME_BINARY_VER/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip
curl -SL $CHROME_URL >headless-chromium.zip
unzip headless-chromium.zip
rm headless-chromium.zip

zip -r ../../chrome_headless.zip *
```

**Error:**

> Collecting selenium==3.141.0   Downloading
> selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (904 kB)
> 904 kB 1.8 MB/s Collecting urllib3   Downloading urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
> 138 kB 5.9 MB/s Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium Successfully installed
> selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.26.8 WARNING: You are using pip version
> 21.0; however, version 22.0.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the '/var/lang/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade
> pip' command. ./docker-script-layer-linux.sh: line 16: **pushd:
> build/chrome_headless: No such file or directory   % To**tal    %
> Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 3987k  100 3987k    0     0  7250k      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:-- 7236k ./docker-script-layer-linux.sh: line 20: unzip: command not found   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time
> Time     Time  Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   685  100   685    0     0   1495      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--  1498 100 43.4M  100 43.4M    0     0  9496k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 10.3M

Comment: Do you mean to write this sequence of steps into a Dockerfile, perhaps?  A couple of lines above you refer to a `out/build/...` directory; do you mean to change to that directory in the problematic line?

Comment: Yes, right. Want to do all operations in a container and as a result, need a zip file in local machine @DavidMaze Any suggestion

Comment: Of what you show, only the one `pip install` line runs in a container; everything else runs directly on the host.  Would a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) be a better match for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below dockerfile to do above task

```
FROM lambci/lambda:python3.7

ENV SELENIUM_VER=3.141.0
#based on Chromium 69.0.3497.81
ENV CHROME_BINARY_VER=v1.0.0-55 
# supports Chrome v69-71
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VER=2.43

ENV RUNTIME=python3.7
USER root
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN yum -y install zip unzip

# Directory in container for project source files
ENV OUT_DIR=/out/build/chrome_headless/python/lib/$RUNTIME/site-packages
# Install Python dependencies

RUN mkdir -p $OUT_DIR
RUN pip install selenium==$SELENIUM_VER --target $OUT_DIR



WORKDIR /out/build/chrome_headless

ENV DRIVER_URL=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VER/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN curl -SL $DRIVER_URL >chromedriver.zip
RUN dir
RUN unzip chromedriver.zip
RUN rm chromedriver.zip

# download chrome binary
ENV CHROME_URL=https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/$CHROME_BINARY_VER/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip
RUN curl -SL $CHROME_URL >headless-chromium.zip
RUN unzip headless-chromium.zip
RUN rm headless-chromium.zip
RUN zip -r chrome_headless.zip *
```